# Какую причину закрытия вопроса выбрать, если вопрос не по теме?

Tags: поддержка, причины-закрытия

Где пункт не по теме, потому что не по теме?
Какой из этих пунктов выбирать, если вопрос про то [как зайти в систему в самолёте](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/834785/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C%D1%81%D1%8F-%D0%B2-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BF%D1%8C%D1%8E%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80-%D0%B2-%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B5-%D0%B2-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B5-%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D0%BD%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD-%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%82), или [про установку Linux](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/834462/%D0%A3%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0-linux-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D0%BF%D1%83%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA), или про то [как растянуть картинку в фотошопе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/833750/%D0%98%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%88%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%B0-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%B2-photoshop), или [про вид насекомых, лезущих в дом](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/838907/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5-%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE-%D0%B2%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B8)?

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Который раз уже тема поднимается)

Comment: @Suvitruf предлагайте дубликат для закрытия :)

Comment: @Suvitruf Значит это жу-жу-жу неспроста. Надо добавить пункт "не по теме, потому-что не соотвествует тематике нашего загончика", потому что каждый раз руками писать немного утомляет.

Comment: Запулил [фича-реквест](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/310575/339911) на MSE.

Comment: На самом деле, если вопрос никак не связан с IT, лучше всего не закрывать, а ставить тревогу "Необходимо удалить из-за проблем с качеством" и удалять через очередь низкого качества. Таким образом от них можно избавляться куда быстрее, чем через переполненную очередь закрытия.

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight это не дубликат. Там предложение добавить пункт, а здесь — вопрос о том, что выбрать.

Comment: Глистов - в спам. И айфоны - в спам. Если есть слова "цена" "услуга" или смысл сводится к тому что нужно что-то купить - это СПАМ. Так же под СПАМ подпадают безсмысленные предложения "что бы про что-то узнали". Всякие слухи сплетни. Пустышки которые ничего не значат.

Answer (score 7):

В текущей ситуации стоит выбирать "Другое", добавляя некоторое, пусть и очевидное, объяснения. На enSO же есть пункт вида:

- > Blatantly off-topic (this question has nothing to do with programming)

который очень хорошо сюда подходит под описанную ситуацию. <s>Возможно, когда скорость появления  вопросов не по теме превысит некий порог, такой пункт появится и у нас. Хотя, можно и менеджера попросить пролить свет на ситуацию, я считаю.</s>

Как выяснилось в комментариях, пункт **"явно не по теме"** доступен для участников, которые ещё не получили привилегию голосовать за закрытие и могут только ставить тревоги. Мне кажется, что подобный пункт хорошо бы сохранить и для более реповитых участников, в связи с чем, я оформил feature-request на Meta StackExchange: [Blatantly off-topic for all](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/310575/339911).

Comment: Пожалуйста, допишите по-русски причину, мы не на enSO. Я использую формулировку вида "вопрос не относится ни к программированию, ни к системному администрированию".

Comment: @AK учитывая периодические попытки расширить онтопик, итоговую строку надо собирать. Можно поиск этой строки выделить в отдельный вопрос.

Comment: А что тут проливать, "Явно не по теме (вопрос никак не связан со stackoverflow на русском)", отображается только для пользователей без права голосования за закрытие.

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight любопытно. Чего бы не оставить эту причину и после получения соответствующих привилегий.

Comment: Не согласен. Не надо отправлять вопрос в очередь на закрытие.

Comment: @alexolut потому что вред от наличия этой причины закрытия может быть больше пользы. Редко когда вопросы спрашивают типа: «как отварить яйца» или «как, когда и какую паклю использовать для водопроводного крана», поэтому можно и ручками написать в таких случаях: «вопрос не относится к разработке ПО или сисадминству. Возможно вас больше подойдёт seasonedadvice.SE». Небольшое трение полезно, чтобы люди не размышляя лишние вопросы бы не закрывали.

Comment: @jfs в чём вред-то? Думаете, будут злоупотреблять? Так модераторы подскажут, что так делать не стоит.

Comment: @alexolut Забавно то, что на мете есть причина закрытия "Не по теме → Скорее всего, данный вопрос не относится ни к обсуждению работы сайта Stack Overflow на русском, ни к программному обеспечению сети Stack Exchange, согласно правилам, описанным в справке.", что аналогично причине закрытия "Явно не по теме…", а на основном сайте такого нет.

Answer (score -3):

> Какой из этих пунктов выбирать, если вопрос про собачьих глистов или цену айфона?

Никакой. Ставить Тревога -> Спам. На каждую такую тревогу пост получает по минусу от Духа, а при шесть таких тревогах (или меньше, если тревогу ставит модератор) вопрос удаляется, а его содержимое скрывается и доступно только в списке ревизий.

Comment: Но ведь это не спам!

Comment: Давайте уже определимся, либо нам формулировку поменять в диалоге тревог, либо следовать ей. Потому что сейчас под этой тревогой пояснение *"Рекламирует продукт или услугу, не раскрывая при этом причастность автора."*. Ни слова про оффтопик.